# What casts are allowed with `as`?

Tags: casting, rust

[The Rust Book section on the `as` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html) currently says

> The as keyword does basic casting:

```
let x: i32 = 5;

let y = x as i64;
```

> It only allows certain kinds of casting, however.

What are those *certain kinds* of allowed casting?

A since-deleted answer here explained that sometimes you need to chain multiple `as`-casts to accomplish a safe result, that can't be done in a single step. When is that necessary?

Comment: FWIW, the Rust docs are pretty responsive to issues suggesting enhancements. Or even better, take the answer(s) here and submit a PR to the docs for everyone to benefit!

Comment: Yep, I was going to do just that.

Comment: Started in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/30088

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that this is documented very well, but [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/219eca11b044de3644b3e9101124513c1a842b09/src/librustc_typeck/check/cast.rs#L11) is some information you might find useful:

> A cast `e as U` is valid if one of the following holds:
>
> - `e` has type `T` and `T` coerces to `U`; *coercion-cast*
> - `e` has type `*T`, `U` is `*U_0`, and either `U_0: Sized` or
>     unsize_kind(`T`) = unsize_kind(`U_0`); *ptr-ptr-cast*
> - `e` has type `*T` and `U` is a numeric type, while `T: Sized`; *ptr-addr-cast*
> - `e` is an integer and `U` is `*U_0`, while `U_0: Sized`; *addr-ptr-cast*
> - `e` has type `T` and `T` and `U` are any numeric types; *numeric-cast*
> - `e` is a C-like enum and `U` is an integer type; *enum-cast*
> - `e` has type `bool` or `char` and `U` is an integer; *prim-int-cast*
> - `e` has type `u8` and `U` is `char`; *u8-char-cast*
> - `e` has type `&[T; n]` and `U` is `*const T`; *array-ptr-cast*
> - `e` is a function pointer type and `U` has type `*T`,
>     while `T: Sized`; *fptr-ptr-cast*
> - `e` is a function pointer type and `U` is an integer; *fptr-addr-cast*
>
> where `&.T` and `*T` are references of either mutability,
>   and where unsize_kind(`T`) is the kind of the unsize info
>   in `T` - the vtable for a trait definition (e.g. `fmt::Display` or
>   `Iterator`, not `Iterator<Item=u8>`) or a length (or `()` if `T: Sized`).
>
> Note that lengths are not adjusted when casting raw slices -
>   `T: *const [u16] as *const [u8]` creates a slice that only includes
>   half of the original memory.
>
> Casting is not transitive, that is, even if `e as U1 as U2` is a valid
>   expression, `e as U2` is not necessarily so (in fact it will only be valid if
>   `U1` coerces to `U2`).

Comment: Casting an integer to a pointer seems unsafe. Maybe this list is out of date since the doc says `as` only does safe casts (now?)

Comment: @poolie: it still works [[playpen link](http://is.gd/7sLMbt)]. casting an integer into a pointer isn't unsafe but dereferencing a pointer is.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [The Rustonomicon: Casts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/casts.html)

> Here's an exhaustive list of all the true casts. For brevity, we will use * to denote either a *const or *mut, and integer to denote any integral primitive:
>
> - *T as *U where T, U: Sized
> - *T as *U TODO: explain unsized situation
> - *T as integer
> - integer as *T
> - number as number
> - C-like-enum as integer
> - bool as integer
> - char as integer
> - u8 as char
> - &[T; n] as *const T
> - fn as *T where T: Sized
> - fn as integer